# Free memory outside function

Tags: c, memory-management

Is this going to leak memory or is it ok? Please also let me know if there is something else that I need to pay attention to.

```
typedef struct 
{
int len;
UC * message; 
}pack;

pack * prepare_packet_to_send(const int length,const unsigned char tag,const int numargs, ... )
{

pack *layer=  malloc(sizeof(pack));
va_list listp;
va_start( listp, numargs );
int step = 0;
layer->message = (unsigned char *) malloc(length);
layer->len = length;
int i = 0;
int len = 0;
unsigned char *source_message ; 

for( i = 0 ; i < numargs; i++ )
{

source_message = va_arg( listp, unsigned char *);
len = va_arg( listp, long);
memcpy(layer->message+step, source_message, (long) len);
step+=len;
}

va_end( listp );
 return layer;
}


main()

{

pack *test = call prepare_packet_to_send(sizeof(var1)+sizeof(var2),any tag,any args) 

// are following two frees correct/enough? or is there something else i need to do to     prevent mem leak?

free(test->message);
free(test);


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

As you've used it here, I don't see a memory leak, so that would be a "no."

The function itself, however allocates memory without ever freeing it, so it's pretty much a memory leak waiting to happen -- the client code has to free the memory it allocates. Worse, freeing that memory is slightly non-trivial (two separate `free`s that have to happen in the right order) so it's not *just* a matter of whoever uses it *remembering* to free the memory, but there's also a possibility of them doing it wrong even if they do remember. Granted, it's not terribly complex either, but I'd still probably add a little function like:

```
void destroy_sent_packet(pack *p) { 
    free(p->message);
    free(p);
}
```

So it's at least back to the client just remembering to free the memory.

Comment: Thank you so much, so If I understood you correctly, as long as I use your free function after each call it won't leak?